# Why the value isn't increasing int Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am confused about why it is not increasing. Actually, I am making a voting panel, where user can vote and on voting, it increases database. But that doesn't happen.

```
int votes=0;

public void voteit(String party){
    final int[] v = {0};
    allpoliticalparty= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("votes");
    allpoliticalparty.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            v[0] =Integer.parseInt(value)+1;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
        votes=v[0]++;
    allpoliticalparty.setValue("" + votes);
}
```

I have also tried static int votes=0; Then it increments only once then it didn't increases.

Comment: You made v final.  Perhaps you can’t update it for that reason.  Remove final from `int[] v` and see what happens.

Comment: @ManLaw the variable reference can't change, the values actually can. `final` is onyl working for the reference

Answer (score 2):

That's not a proper way in which you should incremenet a value. Because we are developing applications that can be used in a multiuser environment, you should consider using a transaction. Please see the following method, it will help you increase/decrease the value of your `votes` property:

```
public static void setVotes(String operation) {
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference votesRef = rootRef.child("votes");
    votesRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Integer votes = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
            if (votes == null) {
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            if (operation.equals("increaseScore")) {
                mutableData.setValue(votes + 1);
            } else if (operation.equals("decreaseScore")){
                mutableData.setValue(votes - 1);
            }

            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
    });
}
```

And then kick it off with:

```
setScore("increaseScore");
```

For more informations please check the official documentation regarding [saving data as transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

Comment: I started writing answer on transactions and then I saw your answer. Also maybe add a sentence or two on what transactions are and why to use them.

Comment: Well.. @AlexMamo, I don't think he's doing that. I've got so many unaccepted right answers from new users.

Comment: @VedprakashWagh I hope they'll understand at some point in time how this works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you keep retrieving the same number because you never update it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple update example.

```
private void writeNewPost(String userId, String username, String title, String 
 body) {
// Create new post at /user-posts/$userid/$postid and at
// /posts/$postid simultaneously
String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey();
Post post = new Post(userId, username, title, body);
Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();

Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put("/posts/" + key, postValues);
childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + "/" + key, postValues);

mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```